# JS Knock not creating view objects - How are view objects created?

Tags: javascript

[image: screenshot of js knockout code]

I am working on a program called OpenEMR.
I was asked to add some data to a page that is loaded by JS Knockout. I am learning about this JS Knockout as I go through this exercise.

The problem is that after added the new object.

```
function patient_data_view_model(pname,pid,pubpid,str_dob,regdate)
{
    var self=this;
    self.pname=ko.observable(pname);
    self.pid=ko.observable(pid);
    self.pubpid=ko.observable(pubpid);
    self.str_dob=ko.observable(str_dob);
    self.regdate=ko.observable(regdate);  //new object
```

I added it to all the locations following the pattern that was set by the original writer.
I installed a js knockout plugging in the browser to help troubleshoot the issue when the data did not show up on the screen. Yes, the data is being loaded by this

```
    function setMyPatient() {
            parent.left_nav.setPatient("Hung Chow (she)",66499, " | MRN: 66499",''," DOB: 01\/08\/1996 | Age: 25 | Gender ID \"F\" | ",''," Reg Date: 03\/09\/2021");
```

As you can observe in the screenshot the redate is not being created.

My question is what creates the objects like the pname function that on the right? It is obviously not the mere fact of adding the ko.observable.

The other place that was updated was here.

```
left_nav.setPatient = function(pname, pid, pubpid, frname, str_dob, regdate)
{
    if((app_view_model.application_data.patient()!==null) && (pid===app_view_model.application_data.patient().pid()))
    {
        app_view_model.application_data.patient().pname(pname);
        app_view_model.application_data.patient().pubpid(pubpid);
        app_view_model.application_data.patient().str_dob(str_dob);
        app_view_model.application_data.patient().regdate(regdate);

        return;
    }
```

This function seems to be the point at which the data is applied to the view.

Thanks!

Comment: Please ensure your sample data is not the actual patient data

Comment: Hung Chow is not a real patient or a real person.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly (and I'm making a few assumptions here, as you left out some relevant information):

1. There is a patient-object stored in `app_view_model.application_data.patient` (wrapped in an observable)
2. There is a constructor function for these patient objects called `patient_data_view_model`
3. You added a parameter `regdate` to this constructor that add an extra property `regdate` to the patient objects it creates
4. There is a function `left_nav.setPatient` that takes some values and overrides the current values of the patient currently stored in `app_view_model.application_data.patient`
5. **Issue:** Newly created patient-objects don't contain this new property `regdate`

Well, the relevant information you left out is where this patient object is actually created. I would expect something somewhere along the lines of:

```js
app_view_model.application_data.patient = ko.observable(new patient_data_view_model('abc', 123, 456, 'def', '01-02-2021');
```

If it is created this way, it indeed should contain the new `regdate` field. If it was created any other way, all bets are off.

By the way, calling this `setPatient` function without the `regdate` field being present should give an error that says something like "regdate is not a function".

Comment: Line 38 var new_patient=new patient_data_view_model(pname,pid,pubpid,str_dob,regdate);

Comment: app_view_model.application_data.patient(new_patient);